# Pair Macbook with sensor device over Bluetooth LE

Tags: macos, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

For the needs of a university project I have to connect my Macbook Air to a Bluetooth LE device (an air pollution sensor). When looking for nearby devices my Mac cannot find this sensor device and probably the reason is that it uses Bluetooth LE.

Do you know what kind of drivers or special framework do I need to connect to this device using Bluetooth LE?

Comment: And what's your code?

Comment: I don't have any code.That is actually what I am asking. I cannot find this device at all. Should I download some drivers or should I edit some code files of the OS?

Comment: Have you tried third party apps? What do you get when you scan for devices. If you haven't tried third party apps, use lightBlue that is available on the App Store for MacOS. Make sure of the following things : 1) Does your MacBook Air have Bluetooth v4.0 hardware? and 2) Can you see the sensor when scanning from other devices?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to find BLE devices in your Bluetooth device search. In order to find the devices you are going to have write code in objective C using the CoreBluetooth framework. Also you need to make sure your Air supports BLE. I believe the early ones don't.